# EventListener problems in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a piece of code that I'm having problems with, it seems that even though I tell it do so the event listener is not being removed resulting in the 1009 error on frame 2.

Here is the code:

```
stop();
import flash.events.Event;
var loaded:Number
var total:Number;
var percent1:Number;
var percent2;

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent);
    function enterFrameEvent(event:Event):void{
    loaded = this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    total = this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    percent1 = loaded/total;
    percent2 = percent1 * 100;
    loadingBar.scaleX = percent1;
    playButton.alpha = percent1;
    if(loaded===total){playButton.alpha = 1};
        }
    if (loaded === total){removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent)}

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
    function mouseClick (event:MouseEvent){
    if (playButton.alpha == 1){
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
        gotoAndPlay(2);

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your condition (`laded === total`) is being met?

Answer (score 1):

try..

```
 if (loaded == total){removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent)}
```

instead  of ...

```
 if (loaded === total){removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent)}
```

the difference being == (equality operator) and ===(strict equality operator). Hope that works.